# Spring cant connect to mysql database after computer restarted how can i diagnose what is wrong

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm using spring to connect to a mysql database on the same machine and pull data from an api and store it. It was working Yesterday and i decided to leave it running to see if i hit any issues. It worked perfectly as far as i can tell but i forgot to plug in the laptop and it died. after rebooting the machine up I can connect to the database through command line but my application fails to connect using the same user id and password.

i have tried following the spring.io guide on connecting to mysql again and i have tried messing with my application properties to use 127.0.0.1

i also verified that the credentials worked on the command line and allow me to connect to my mysql database

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/POE?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.profiles.default=production
spring.profiles.active=production
```

pom.xml - mysql connector
...

```
<!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

...

I can show more actual code but it is mostly a rip from the spring.io guides with my own entities. but if i am not making a connection i assume it is not an issue with those

it was running fine and just logging all the writes i was doing to my database but instead now i am getting this error

```
2019-07-09 14:57:45.839 ERROR 2654 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout period of your database. If MySql remains idle for more than 8 hours it is closed by default.

Comment: thats good to know but how to i get reconnected I have also tried sudo service mysql restart

Comment: Did you try changing the wait_timeout in the config file before restart? you can check the timeout using SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'; and change it using SET SESSION wait_timeout = 9999;

Comment: no luck on that either. it was set to 28000 so i changed it to 99999 and restarted but still no luck connecting

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/POE?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.profiles.default=production
spring.profiles.active=production
```

it was a time zone issue buried in the stack trace of the errors i was getting. changing my application properties to this fixed it.